# error in uploading photo on facebook wall using graph API

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am going to work on iphone app which upload the photos on facebook wall.
I am using [this code](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app)

here

```
- (void)rateTapped:(id)sender {

NSString *likeString;
NSString *filePath = nil;
if (_imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"angelina.jpg"]) {
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"angelina" ofType:@"jpg"];
    likeString = @"babe";
} else if (_imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"depp.jpg"]) {
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"depp" ofType:@"jpg"];
    likeString = @"dude";
} else if (_imageView.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"maltese.jpg"]) {
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"maltese" ofType:@"jpg"];
    likeString = @"puppy";
}
if (filePath == nil) return;

NSString *adjectiveString;
if (_segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    adjectiveString = @"cute";
} else {
    adjectiveString = @"ugly";
}

NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I think this is a %@ %@!", adjectiveString, likeString];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request addFile:filePath forKey:@"file"];
//[request setFile:filePath withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"photo"];
[request setPostValue:message forKey:@"message"];
[request setPostValue:_accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(sendToPhotosFinished:)];


[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
}
```

---

**here i got   Photo id is: (null)**

```
 - (void)sendToPhotosFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
// Use when fetching text data
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];
NSString *photoId = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"Photo id is: %@", photoId);

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@?access_token=%@", photoId, [_accessToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
ASIHTTPRequest *newRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(getFacebookPhotoFinished:)];

[newRequest setDelegate:self];
[newRequest startAsynchronous];

}
```

---

```
- (void)getFacebookProfileFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
// Use when fetching text data
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"Got Facebook Profile: %@", responseString);

NSString *likesString;
NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];   
NSArray *interestedIn = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"interested_in"];
if (interestedIn != nil) {
    NSString *firstInterest = [interestedIn objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([firstInterest compare:@"male"] == 0) {
        [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"depp.jpg"]];
        likesString = @"dudes";
    } else if ([firstInterest compare:@"female"] == 0) {
        [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"angelina.jpg"]];
        likesString = @"babes";
    }        
} else {
    [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maltese.jpg"]];
    likesString = @"puppies";
}

NSString *username;
NSString *firstName = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"first_name"];
NSString *lastName = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"last_name"];
if (firstName && lastName) {
    username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
} else {
    username = @"mysterious user";
}

_textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi %@!  I noticed you like %@, so tell me if you think this pic is hot or not!",
                  username, likesString];

[self refresh];    
}
```

But here am suffered from following error

**here in Console i got an error :                                                       Got Facebook Photo: {"error":{"message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: (null)","type":"OAuthException"}}**

**I tried this by changing various App ID but my problem doesn't solve.
Anyone help me to achieve this.........**

Thanks In advance...

Answer (score 0):

You try like this,

```
 NSData *imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(urPhoto, 10);
 [newRequest setPostValue:imagedata forKey:@"data"];
```

or add image like this,

```
 [newRequest setPostValue:link forKey:@"data"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but not understand the : "urlPhoto" I am trying to upload local photo which i capture by camera not form url.

Comment: Here I want to post photo on FB wall . I tried another way it upload only first photo on wall and rest in the album.

Comment: urlPhoto is the UIImage from ur source.AS per I know it will work as u mentioned.First Photo on Wall, Next onwards in the album

Comment: Thanks but I want to disoplay all the photos on wall(neccessory).